# problem with adding Microsoft.WindowsMobile.Status

Tags: c#, compact-framework

when i add Microsoft.WindowsMobile.Status; reference and code

```
private SystemState displayRotationState = new SystemState(SystemProperty.DisplayRotation);
```

i get

```
Error   1   The type 'Microsoft.WindowsMobile.IApplicationLauncher' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsMobile, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.    C:\Projekti\Skladiscenje\Skladiscenje\Skladiscenje\CustomForms\NonFullscreenForm.cs 12  25  Skladiscenje
```

what is wrong and how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error clearly tells you, you should also add a reference to the assembly:

```
Microsoft.WindowsMobile
```

after you do this it should work, ops, compile at least :)